# what does "porn" mean in "word porn"?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

I came across a website/facebook page which posts famous quotes and i wonder what does "**Porn**" mean in this situation ?
I also search many websites but they all believe that it has something to do with *pornography* but i don't think it's relevant to that ..
what do you think ?

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/porn

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is pornography but in a slightly sarcastic usage. The idea is that it's for people who like words/quotes as much as sex or that these quotes are as satisfying to read as porn is to watch.

Comment: I wouldn't make the sexual connection.

Comment: That's part of the sarcastic/joke part, it's not actually sexual.

Answer (score 4):

"Porn" is often used to mean material lavishly presented like pornography, e.g. food porn, which is books, magazines, TV programmes, etc, about food, made to look eye-catching and exciting. Car porn likewise. True porn is mainly about sex, car porn is mainly about cars. Many topics have "porn": gun porn, travel porn. A brewing company in the UK produces what it calls "beer porn". The Facebook page you saw seems to be about words, in a mainly pictorial way. Just as true pornography is principally about sex, other kinds of material designated 'porn' in this way, are also really just about one subject.

Comment: Don't forget "espresso porn".

Comment: I think we're all going to get downvoted to hell, because this is a duplicate question.

Answer (score 1):

It is short for *pornography*. But the term is used playfully  for displays of items that appeal to the senses. Be safe do not have anything to do with sex or naked people. Examples are “food porn” with staged pictures of amazing looking dishes ir “shoe porn” with photos of all the latest shoes.

Comment: There is another kind of shoe porn. I once knew someone who liked it.

Comment: Yeah, I was hesitant to include that example.

Comment: TBF that's true of all the examples ;)

Comment: @Damila "Be safe do not have anything to do with sex or naked people" - that's a recipe for a dull life.